# Retrieving a shared preference value returns null

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I am using shared preference to store a string value in one activity, and but when trying to retrieve the string in some other activity, it returns null.

This is my code below:

Activity A:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor = preferences.edit();

editor.putString("FirstUserName", strUserName);
editor.commit();
```

The above code shows that I am saving the string value in the shared preferences.

Now,

Activity B:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String strUserName = preferences.getString("FirstUserName", null);
```

The above code `preferences.getString("FirstUserName", null)` return null.

I have no idea what the issue could be, I think I have written the code correcly.

If there is any mistake in the code, please revert back.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `SharedPreferences.Editor = preferences.edit();` <-- is this a typo?

Comment: yes.. I think I typed incorrectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In your second Activity you write **"MyPrefs"**, and in the firts
>   Activity you write **"MyPref"** without **"s"**.

Change in your **SecondActivity.java**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: Don't answer a typo question, just vote to close.

Comment: I worked, thank a ton. Didn't see that. Thanks once again!

Answer (score 1):

In Activity A you get `"MyPref"` ,but in Activity B `"MyPrefs"` with an extras 's'. That gets another instance of sharedpreferences that's why you're getting null value. I suggest that you declare these kind of strings in a Constants class.

Comment: Don't answer a typo question, just vote to close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

-> For Store Value :

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putString("firstUserName","user_name");

editor.commit();
editor.apply();

-> For Retrive Value :

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =  getSharedPreferences(
                "MyPref", 0);

Log.e("FirstName", sharedPreferences.getString("firstUserName","");

Comment: it show empty, this is an alternative that if the value doesn't returns. DId this, but didn't work